# How can I use pinch zoom(UIPinchGestureRecognizer) to change width of a UIView

Tags: objective-c, ios, uipinchgesturerecognizer

I can get the `UIPinchGestureRecognizer` handler to work with scaling an object but I don't want to scale I want to change the size. For example I have a `UIView` and I've attacked a `UIPinchGestureRecognizer` gesture to it and if the user pinches I want to change the width of the `UIView` to match the pinch. I don't want to scale it so the `UIView` is larger(zooming)

Comment: You can calculate the new size by multiplying the current frame by the zoom ratio.

Answer (score -2):

If you have the UIPinchGestureRecognizer call a method pinch, you can do:

```
- (void) pinch:(UIPinchGestureRecognizer *)pinch
{
    CGRect frame = [self.view frame];
    frame.size.width = frame.size.width * pinch.scale;
    [self.view setFrame:frame];
}
```